# Javascript Function pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I came across this javascript question in a quiz. Below code returns true. But i dont know how. Can any one explain it please

Topic title: Pattern matching with JavaScript

What value is returned by the following code?

```
function test(form) {
  var str = "apples, oranges, bananas, melons";
  var re = /apple/i;
  var testStr = re.test(str);
  document.write(testStr + "<BR>");
  //Outputs - true 
 }
```

Comment: What about it don't you understand? What value would you expect? Explaining every piece of JavaScript syntax and function (which is what you are asking for since your question is so vague) would be too broad for SO.

Comment: You need to learn [regex](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: The result is an boolean, true if there is a match or false if there isn't.  

Don't write a boolean to your document. 

re is a pattern, the 'i' means case insensitive, thus apple, Apple, APPLE give the same result.

Comment: I think you are confused with the name. First is user defined function name and test() inside function is a pre defined JavaScript function. It some time happens when you are in hurry. Think twice before posting a question over here

Comment: Nothing is _returned_ from the function.

Comment: @Psyche Genie You are Right man.... I am just confused with name.... I am clear now...... Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [w3schools documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp):

> The test() method tests for a match in a string.
>
> This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise it returns
>   false.

Since the `/apple/i` regex will match any string that contains `apple` where the case of the letters is ignored, ie it will match also `Apple`, `APPLE` etc., and since the string `apples, oranges, bananas, melons` contains `apple` the `test()` method returns `true`.

[HTML DOM write()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

> The write() method writes HTML expressions or JavaScript code to a
>   document.
>
> The write() method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an
>   HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

Hence, the `document.write(testStr + "<BR>");`method call writes the result of the test to the document.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation about test() by Mozilla Foundation, with:

- syntax
- description
- examples
- specifications
- browser compatibility
- etc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Example below comes from Mozilla Foundation:

```
function testinput(re, str){
    var midstring;

    if (re.test(str)) {
        midstring = ' contains ';
    } else {
        midstring = ' does not contain ';
    }
    console.log(str + midstring + re.source);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's searches the string `str` for the occurence of `apple` and outputs whether or not it is found.